# Which jquery event is for autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to trigger something after I make the autocomplete to fill in the `#inputField.` This autocomplete is from your form history thing.

I've tried on firefox, and IE. It works in IE, but not firefox.

```
$('#inputField').bind("change keyup", function(){
//do something
});
```

and

```
$('#inputField').on("change keyup", function(){
//do something
});
```

Comment: Not much help, but `change` only fires on non-radio/checkbox inputs after your `blur` in Chrome/Firefox/Opera

Comment: Hi do you now FireBug ? this is an add-on on your browser.Use this to debug your code,This will show you what function is undefined on your FF.

Comment: try key press instead of keyup

Comment: on `keyup` must work in all browsers, [example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onkeyup)

Comment: @ADASein - I tried keypress, it doesn't work on firefox :(

Comment: @bumbumpaw - I tried doing a console.log(), it triggers only when I click away from the inputfield. That's not what I want. It should trigger as soon as you click on the autocomplete and filling the field.

Comment: then try blur instead of change (I think change is for select and file elements mostly, not so sure tho)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you can detect auto-complete, but if you're just trying to detect input (like you're doing in the code in your question), try this:

```
$('#inputField').on('input change propertychange',function(){
    //do something
});
```

- `change` and `propertychange` aren't really necessary or helpful here, because those fire on things like *dropdowns* and *radio-buttons*, but you can just leave them in so you always have the complete check.

From here you could manually check whether it's likely that some of the input is auto-completed, using some intricate coding, like checking if a part of the text is selected...

Comment: you can put 'input' inside an on-event? I didn't know that. This is  what I'm looking for. It works!